# Styling a window

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, windows-shell, skinning

Is there a way to apply styles to WPF Windows? Ex: changing the minimize, maximize, and X buttons? I know the graphics are part of the Windows shell and not WPF, so I wasn't sure if it was possible.

Comment: I've seen it done... in Photoshop. I doubt it. Sorry.

Comment: @ofstream This is absolutely possible and is extremely common.

Comment: ^ I wasn't aware. Please go on...

Comment: Google's your friend!  Add WPF to your queries, and be amazed!

Answer (score 3):

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
x:Class="AccountOperator.CustomWindowStyle"
x:Name="Window"
Title="CustomWindowStyle"
Width="640" Height="480" WindowStyle="None" Margin="0" BorderThickness="2">

<Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MaxButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">         
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border  BorderBrush="#535666" BorderThickness="2,5,2,2" Width="20" Height="15" Background="White"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MinButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border  Width="20" Height="7"  BorderBrush="#535666" BorderThickness="2" Background="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Width="18" Height="4" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#535666" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="50"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                        </Border>
                        <Border Width="18" Height="4" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="#535666" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                            <Border.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform/>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-50"/>
                                    <TranslateTransform/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </Border.RenderTransform>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right">      
        <Button x:Name="BtnMax" Width="20" Height="15" Click="BtnMax_Click" Style="{DynamicResource MaxButtonStyle}" Margin="10"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnClose" Height="18" Width="20" Margin="10"  Style="{DynamicResource CloseButtonStyle}" Click="BtnClose_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="BtnMin" Width="20" Height="20" Style="{DynamicResource MinButtonStyle}" Click="BtnMin_Click" Margin="10"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class CustomWindowStyle : Window
{
    public CustomWindowStyle()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BtnMax_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void BtnMin_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {           
        this.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized; 
    }

    private void BtnClose_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }       
}
```

You just copy and past the above code you get the result what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use to accomplish your task the following project: [wpfwindow.codeplex.com](http://wpfwindow.codeplex.com/).

In this project is file "ButtonIcons.xaml", when you can change properties of those buttons.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

  <!-- MINIMIZE -->
  <Border x:Key="WindowButtonMinimizeIcon" Width="12" Height="5" Margin="0,5,0,0" BorderBrush="#535666" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFF" />

  <!-- MINIMIZE (disabled) -->
  <Border x:Key="WindowButtonMinimizeIconDisabled" Width="12" Height="5" Margin="0,5,0,0" 
          BorderBrush="#9FA5B2" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFFFFF" />

  <!-- RESTORE -->
  <Canvas x:Key="WindowButtonRestoreIcon">
    <Rectangle Stroke="#535666" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Top="1" Canvas.Left="7" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#535666" Fill="White" Width="4" Height="4" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="10" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#535666" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="5" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#535666" Fill="White" Width="4" Height="4" Canvas.Top="6" Canvas.Left="8" />
  </Canvas>

  <!-- RESTORE (disabled) -->
  <Canvas x:Key="WindowButtonRestoreIconDisabled">
    <Rectangle Stroke="#9FA5B2" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Top="1" Canvas.Left="7" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#9FA5B2" Fill="White" Width="4" Height="4" Canvas.Top="4" Canvas.Left="10" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#9FA5B2" Fill="White" Width="10" Height="10" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="5" />
    <Rectangle Stroke="#9FA5B2" Fill="White" Width="4" Height="4" Canvas.Top="6" Canvas.Left="8" />
  </Canvas>

  <!-- MAXIMIZE -->
  <Border x:Key="WindowButtonMaximizeIcon" BorderBrush="#535666" BorderThickness="1" Width="12" Height="10">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FCFCFC" BorderThickness="2">
      <Border BorderBrush="#535666" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Border>
  </Border>


  <!-- MAXIMIZE (disabled) -->
  <Border x:Key="WindowButtonMaximizeIconDisabled" BorderBrush="#9FA5B2" BorderThickness="1" Width="12" Height="10">
    <Border BorderBrush="#FCFCFC" BorderThickness="2">
      <Border BorderBrush="#9FA5B2" BorderThickness="1" />
    </Border>
  </Border>

  <!-- CLOSE -->
  <Image Source="/CustomWindow;component/Images/buttonX.png" Width="13" Height="10" x:Key="WindowButtonCloseIcon" />

  <!-- Background colors for red button (e.g close button) -->
  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RedButtonBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#F89C8C" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.45" Color="#D47F75" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.45" Color="#C04C3C" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#C98172" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>

  <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RedButtonMouseOverBackground" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#F89C8C" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.45" Color="#E36A53" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.45" Color="#C72B0E" />
    <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="#D44310" />
    <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#F5E478" />
  </LinearGradientBrush>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: This is great, but it more or less just throws the answers at OP.  As I keep re-iterating to folks, don't just give out answers and code when the effort from the asker's perspective shows no motivation.  Don't necessarily make people work too hard for it, but give them a kickstart.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can style windows as you wish.
Unfortunately it is often the question of all or nothing if you want to style title bar, system buttons, window's transeprency or shape.

First, set `Window.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None`
Then you can create new wpf style with `ContolTemplate`.
Likely you'll need to write some code to process window dragging, title bar double clicks, resizing and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to start modifying the xaml.  You might want to start with changing things like the background.

It wasn't quite as simple as I thought.  Initially, I thought you would just change the buttons that you needed, to the buttons you created.  It got a bit more complicated, here.  For instance, making a button look different is not as simple as changing the button background.

You'll need to make specific control templates, or apply a resource to the project, an image, and through XAML, make a `style` or `template` which changes the settings for the image, respectively.

One way I did it, was adding an image, and making a custom control based off the image. No buttons, or other controls were needed.  I then created events for `onclick`, and on mouse over (et cetera), so I effectively made a small image that looked like a button, act like a button.

Things to look at:

`Window.Style`
`Window.Resources`
`Templates`

Honestly, the easiest way to find these answers is asking Google.  You can ask just about anything, but make sure you add **WPF** to the end of it.  That way, you only find answers for WPF specific coding, lots of people operate differently, but you'll find tons of great xaml examples, etc.